# i try use laravel-chunk-upload chunks but files not upload

Tags: laravel, file-upload, upload

there i used this code and resumable js libs to handle ypload huge file

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjekf.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQCST.png)

chunks create successfully

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQXB3.png)

in this folder chunk

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLmys.png)

after progress bar reach to 100% folder chunk become empty and nothing upload to folder lessons

i try to upload huge video , i expected video uploaded to folder lessons

Comment: Please put your code in the question directly, not as screenshots. Is https://github.com/pionl/laravel-chunk-upload the library you are using?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.